# Continuous object rotation around point

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, geometry, computational-geometry, haxe

I want to make a function similar to `rotateAroundInternalPoint()`. So far my solution is this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Point;

addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame );

function onFrame(e:Event):void
{
    var m:Matrix = item.transform.matrix.clone();
    var point:Point = new Point( 50, 50 ); // The object's width and height are 100px, so 50 is the center
    point = m.transformPoint( point );
    m.translate( -point.x, -point.y );

    m.rotate( 5 * ( Math.PI / 180 ) );
    m.translate( point.x, point.y );

    item.transform.matrix = m;
}
```

However there is a fundamental flaw in this code - it gets less and less precise with each iteration.

Could somebody point out what's causing this and what the solution would be?

Comment: I will still accept a better answer that does not depend on a reference matrix but instead relies on better math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem with introducing a reference matrix that would not change, so the mistake from the initial iteration would be non-existent.

Here's the implementation:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Point;

var referenceMatrix:Matrix = item.transform.matrix.clone();

addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame );

var i:Number = 0; // you'll need this because the referenceMatrix rotation will only go one step, so instead you need to increase the rotation

function onFrame(e:Event):void
{
    var m:Matrix = referenceMatrix.clone();
    var point:Point = new Point( 100, 100 ); // pivot point local to the object's coordinates

    point = m.transformPoint( point );
    m.translate( -point.x, -point.y );
    m.rotate( i * ( Math.PI / 180 ) );
    m.translate( point.x, point.y );
    item.transform.matrix = m;

    i += 1.2; // rotation step
}
```

Please note that this code is written in a frame and isn't well-optimized for real use, rather it illustrates the algorithm.